# attacker is to defender as challenger is to ..?

Tags: word-choice

In an aggressive fight, you have an "attacker" and a "defender".

In a friendly match, you have a "challenger", and someone who accepts and responds to the challenge (accepts the match).  He could be the "opponent", or "belligerent", but I'm looking for a word that says "he accepted the friendly challenge."

Comment: Not challengee!  It's not distinctive enough.

Comment: I don’t know about a single word, but “My seconds will meet with your seconds in the morning” sounds like the proposal — or perhaps acceptance — of a duel.  The classic response of course being “Oh really? My seconds will meet with your seconds in the alley.” :)

Comment: How about "defender" (again)? "Attacker" sounds aggressive, but "defender" not so much..

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment that *defender* is a fairly suitable correspondent to *challenger*.  But depending on the context and phrasing,  *challenged* and  *incumbent*  may also work, as illustrated in the following sentences.

> • Alice was the challenger, and Bob the challenged party.
>   • Alice was the challenger; Bob was the [incumbent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incumbent#Noun).

Comment: Hmm, incumbent.  While I like the word, it kind of implies "reigning champion", which isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: Where does incumbency figure in this?

Comment: @Kris, the pair of words *challenger* and *incumbent* often are used in describing election contests; and as bobobobo hints in comment, *challenger* and *champion* are often similarly paired in sports contests.

Comment: *The current holder of an office,* or *A holder of a position* is irrelevant here.

Comment: It's not very sporting to attack someone while he's holding an office.